# Meaning of "Evaluation for inpatient hospitalization, either by on-site psychiatric professional or through an emergency room"

Tags: terminology, psychiatrist-psychiatry

From [Table 5](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5777328/table/T5/?report=objectonly) in *[Psychiatric Emergencies: Assessing and Managing Suicidal Ideation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5777328/)*

> Evaluation for inpatient hospitalization, either by on-site psychiatric professional or through an emergency room.

Does it mean "evaluation by on-site psychiatric professional", or does it mean "hospitalization by on-site psychiatric professional"?

"Hospitalization" seems to fit well to "through an emergency room", but "evaluation" seems to fit well to "psychiatric professional". But the sentence is constructed in such a way that a single noun (either **evaluation** or **hospitalization**) commands both prepositional phrases.

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Suicidal patients are not hospitalized in a regular hospital unless they have a medical problem which must be stabilized before inpatient psychiatric facility admission is possible. If this does not modify your question, please explain what facilities and specialties you're referring to, as it's unclear to me, and I've done lots of evaluations from the ED. Medical doctors (at least in our ED) rarely determined the need for psychiatric admission (we consulted Crisis Intervention to do so, unless it was glaringly obvious, e.g. we had to suture their wrists first.)

Comment: Although the language isn’t clear, I suspect what they mean is evaluation for inpatient psychiatric hospitalization by a mental health professional, either at the site or through an emergency department. Our physicians in my ED don’t usually determine the need for psychiatric admission. We do have a team here of social workers and psychiatrists that do.

Comment: @Risky_91 - thank you!